# Como passar um array para uma propriedade?

Tags: array, delphi, propriedade

Estou tentando passar um array de Strings e dois arrays de TAlignment para três propriedades (published). Mas estou tendo o seguinte erro (que é o mesmo para as três propriedades):

> [dcc32 Error] uCad.pas(31): E2188 Published property 'ColumnTitleName' cannot be of type ARRAY".

O código está abaixo:

```
type
    TCad = class
    private
      FColumnTitleName: array of String;
      FColumnTitleAlign: array of TAlignment;
      FColumnAlign: array of TAlignment;
      function GetColumnAlign(index: Integer): TAlignment;
      function GetColumnTitleAlign(index: Integer): TAlignment;
      function GetColumnTitleName(index: Integer): String;
    public

    published
      property ColumnTitleName[index: Integer]: String read GetColumnTitleName;
      property ColumnTitleAlign[index: Integer]: TAlignment read GetColumnTitleAlign;
      property ColumnAlign[index: Integer]: TAlignment read GetColumnAlign;
  end;

implementation

function TCad.GetColumnAlign(index: Integer): TAlignment;
begin
  Result := FColumnAlign[index];
end;

function TCad.GetColumnTitleAlign(index: Integer): TAlignment;
begin
  Result := FColumnTitleAlign[index];
end;

function TCad.GetColumnTitleName(index: Integer): String;
begin
  Result := FColumnTitleName[index];
end;

end.
```

Alguém sabe onde estou errando ?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Parece um problema semelhante a este

[Delphi _Como passar dados para uma propriedade do tipo array de record](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263648/delphi-como-passar-dados-para-uma-propriedade-do-tipo-array-de-record/263857#263857)

Podes também ter de declarar um type para esse array. Por vezes nao se pode usar o array of [algo] diretamente.

Comment: Oi Tiago. Obrigado pela resposta. Eu havia visto esse post que você mencionou. Infelizmente não há jeito de resolver, porque o Delphi não aceita array em properties. Resolvi tornando as properties públicas em vez de published. Abraço.

Comment: Desculpa, podes explicar melhor a diferença entre o teu problema e o desse post? Lá tens array em properties, ou nao?

Comment: É por serem published certo? Já aprendi alguma coisa hj :p

Comment: É isso mesmo. A partir do momento em que movi as declarações property que estavam em published para public,o código acima funcionou. Ou seja, não dá para colocar array em uma propriedade no Object Inspector, mas dá para passar um array para uma propriedade por código. []s.